# ckeditor4, remove vertical scroll unless needed

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I'm using [CKEditor 4](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/) and I'm looking to find out how to hide the vertical scrollbar until it's needed. Their demos do this, but for some reason mine seems to always show it.

I've looked through the documentation but I can't find a specific area that talks about scrollbars. Could someone please point me in the right direction? :)

Answer (score 0):

It probably would be an issue of style property - Height / Overflow.

But it would be helpful, if you would share some details about it via Screenshot or Code..?